# Using Apache POI to extract excel text type attachment encode issue

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am now using Apache POI to extract the attachments from the Excel file, here is part of my code.

```java
    Sheet sheetAt = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    Drawing<?> drawingPatriarch = sheetAt.getDrawingPatriarch();
    if (drawingPatriarch != null) {
        Iterator<?> iterator = drawingPatriarch.iterator();
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Object next = iterator.next();
            if (next instanceof ObjectData) {
                ObjectData o = (ObjectData) next;
                IOUtil.write(o.getObjectData(), outputPath);
            } else if (next instanceof Picture) {
                Picture o = (Picture) next;
                IOUtil.write(o.getData(), outputPath);
            } 
        }
    }
```

When the attachment is a binary type, such as exe, png, etc., the file extracted in this way is normal, but if the attachment is a text type, such as txt, pdf, etc., the extracted file can not be opened normally, view the binary content, in addition to the original file has a lot of extra data, how do I parse this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your `ObjectData` is of type `oleObject` or `Objekt-Manager-Shellobjekt`. Those objects are stored in embedded `oleObject*.bin` files. Those files have file systems of their own which need to be read. To do so, first get the `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectoryNode` and then get the [Ole10Native](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/Ole10Native.html). Having that you can get the file data as `byte[] data = ole10Native.getDataBuffer()`.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;

public class ExcelGetObjectData {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //String inFilePath = "./ExcelExampleIn.xlsx"; String outFilePath = "./ExcelExampleOut.xlsx";
  String inFilePath = "./ExcelExampleIn.xls"; String outFilePath = "./ExcelExampleOut.xls";
  
  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(inFilePath));
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFilePath ) ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
   Drawing<?> drawingPatriarch = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
   if (drawingPatriarch != null) {
    for (Shape shape : drawingPatriarch) {
     System.out.println(shape);
     if (shape instanceof ObjectData) {
      ObjectData objectData = (ObjectData) shape;
      System.out.println(objectData.getFileName());
      System.out.println(objectData.getOLE2ClassName());
      System.out.println(objectData.getContentType());
      if(objectData.getOLE2ClassName().equals("Objekt-Manager-Shellobjekt")) {
       if (objectData.hasDirectoryEntry()) {
        DirectoryEntry directory = objectData.getDirectory();
        if (directory instanceof DirectoryNode) {
         DirectoryNode directoryNode = (DirectoryNode)directory;
         Ole10Native ole10Native = Ole10Native.createFromEmbeddedOleObject(directoryNode);
         System.out.println(ole10Native.getCommand());
         System.out.println(ole10Native.getFileName());
         System.out.println(ole10Native.getLabel());
         byte[] data = ole10Native.getDataBuffer(); //data now contains the embedded data
         try (FileOutputStream dataOut = new FileOutputStream("./" + ole10Native.getLabel())) {
          dataOut.write(data);
         }
        }
       }
      } else if(objectData.getOLE2ClassName().equals("...")) {
       //...
      }          
     } else if (shape instanceof /*other*/Object) {
      //...
     }
    }        
   }
   
   workbook.write(out);
  }
 }
}
```

Using [EmbeddedExtractor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/extractor/EmbeddedExtractor.html) extraction of all embedded objects could be done like so:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.extractor.EmbeddedExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.extractor.EmbeddedData;

public class ExcelEmbeddedExtractor {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String inFilePath = "./ExcelExampleIn.xlsx"; String outFilePath = "./ExcelExampleOut.xlsx";
  //String inFilePath = "./ExcelExampleIn.xls"; String outFilePath = "./ExcelExampleOut.xls";
  
  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(inFilePath));
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFilePath ) ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
   EmbeddedExtractor extractor = new EmbeddedExtractor();
   for (EmbeddedData embeddedData : extractor.extractAll(sheet)) {
    Shape shape = embeddedData.getShape();
    System.out.println(shape);    
    String filename = embeddedData.getFilename();
    System.out.println(filename);   
    byte[] data = embeddedData.getEmbeddedData(); //data now contains the embedded data
    try (FileOutputStream dataOut = new FileOutputStream("./" + filename)) {
     dataOut.write(data);
    }    
   }
   
   workbook.write(out);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Using `objectData.getOLE2ClassName()` always returns "Package", but it is still possible to use `Ole10Native` to decode ObjectData and the result is correct. Thank you very much for solving my problem.

Comment: I have another problem, when extracting e.g. doc, ppt, xls from xls, I can't get the actual content using the above method and I can't get any data from `ObjectData.getData()`.

Comment: I found this class `org.apache.poi.ss.extractor.EmbeddedExtractor` that can provide some help.

Comment: @516628: Your question was about text type attachment. When extracting e.g. doc or ppt attachments, you get different `getOLE2ClassName`: "Document" or "Word.Document", "Presentation" or "PowerPoint.Show". Those have to be handled different.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your reply, I can now parse doc, docx, xls, ppt, pptx, etc., but there are still some formats that cannot be parsed correctly, for example xlsx, I tried to parse it using `org.apache.poi.ss.extractor.EmbeddedExtractor. OOXMLExtractor`, but the parsed data cannot be opened by Office. Can you provide some reference on how to parse, or related online documents to learn about it.

Comment: @516628: I know that `org.apache.poi.ss.extractor.EmbeddedExtractor` also has issues sometimes. So I have no answer that fits all cases.